# How do I get value from JSON using JsonPath in Java?

Tags: java, json, jsonpath

I want to get the value from the JSON object using JsonPath.Could anyone please suggest me the appropriate jars which i would need because as per my knowledge i am getting this exception for the jars i am using for jsonpath .

```
package jsonPg;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath;

public class ReadJsonPath {

    static String file = "D:\\AutomationSample\\Sample_Json.txt";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JSONException, IOException {
        JsonReadFile jsonReadFile=new JsonReadFile();
        JSONObject jsonObj=jsonReadFile.parseJSONFile(file);
        String jsonObject=jsonObj.toString();
        String json="";
        System.out.println(jsonObject);
//      Object val = JsonPath.read(jsonObject,"");
        String val1=JsonPath.read(jsonObject," $.payload[*].supplierDataMap[*].COMPANYDETAILS.customFieldList[*].DISPLAYGSID   .value");
        System.out.println(val1);

     }

 }
```

here is the code which i have written and below is the exception which is thrown at runtime

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: FACTORY_SIMPLE
     at com.jayway.jsonpath.spi.impl.JsonSmartJsonProvider.<init>(JsonSmartJsonProvider.java:38)
at com.jayway.jsonpath.spi.impl.JsonSmartJsonProvider.<init>(JsonSmartJsonProvider.java:41)
at com.jayway.jsonpath.spi.JsonProviderFactory.<clinit>  (JsonProviderFactory.java:24)
at    com.jayway.jsonpath.Configuration.defaultConfiguration(Configuration.java:62)
at com.jayway.jsonpath.internal.JsonReader.<init>(JsonReader.java:26)
at com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath.read(JsonPath.java:462)
at jsonPg.ReadJsonPath.main(ReadJsonPath.java:27)`
```

Any kind of help would be appreciated .
Thanks in advance .

Comment: Did U checked your path? That can be done using one of many online tools, e.g. [jsonpath.com](http://jsonpath.com/).

Comment: yes i have checked the jsonPath . it is working properly.. i just need to make that work in java code

Comment: Could you maybe share json?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can achieve your goal with `JsonPath` library on its own. Here is an example:

```
    String jsonString = "{ \"list\": [ { \"name\": \"foo1\"}, { \"name\": \"foo2\"} ]}";
    DocumentContext docCtx = JsonPath.parse(jsonString);
    JsonPath jsonPath = JsonPath.compile("$.list[?(@.name == \"foo1\")]");
    JSONArray val1=docCtx.read(jsonPath);
    System.out.println(val1);
```

This code will print out:

```
[{"name":"foo1"}]
```

Required maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
    <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

`json-path` will also automatically pull `json-smart` JAR:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.minidev</groupId>
    <artifactId>json-smart</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   String jsonString = "{ \"list\": [ { \"name\": \"foo1\"}, { \"name\": \"foo2\"} ]}";
    DocumentContext docCtx = JsonPath.parse(jsonString);
    JsonPath jsonPath = JsonPath.compile("$.list[?(@.name == foo1)]");
    JSONArray val1=docCtx.read(jsonPath);
    System.out.println(val1);
```